# Lotus: @DBlookup for every row in view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

please help me with a following problem:
I have 2 forms: "EmpsAll" (all employees) and EmpsDocs (employees which, for example, signed a document in company).
And I need to build a view to show the employee name in first column and boolean info (0 or 1) depend on is the employee in the EmpsDocs base (if employee is in EmpsDocs then returns 1, if not returns 0).
The question is: is it possible to enter a formula @BDLookup to second column to calculate value (0 or 1) idividually for every employ in the view?

Comment: Are these two forms in the same database? Are they different databases? Is the employee name on the EmpsDocs document? Instead of creating a separate form to record that they signed the document, why not just put a value on their EmpsAll document indicating that they signed the document? Trying to treat Notes like a relational database is going to lead to some very poor design decisions.

Comment: Yes there two forms are in the same database but EmpsDocs contains the important data about documents that has been signed by employee so one field in EmpsAll is not enough. I added a new field in EmpAll ("IsSigned") and wrote an agent that for all documents in EpmAll search EmpNo in EmpsDoc. If found agent puts the value 1 to IsSigned field, if no the value is 0. And the view shows all data from EmpsAll where IsSigned=0. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use @DBLookup in a view column formula.  A good alternative is to write a scheduled agent that iterates over all documents in one view, does the @DBLookup, and changes a value in the document.

The good news is your view is fast since there are no lookups, but the bad is your view is showing a snapshot in time of the state of all documents.

Comment: Ken is correct.  The restriction on use in view formulas is documented in the help page for @DbLookup in the Domino Designer help file.  It's a long and detailed help page, so it's easy to miss.  "Usage: This function does not work in column or selection formulas, or in mail agents."

Comment: Thanks, your answer inspire me to do this by agent. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that inside a repeat control with XPages, if that is an option.

Comment: I'm a beginner in Lotus programming so I write an application for Lotus client as yet. But thank you for your answer, I try it later.

Answer (score 0):

I read what you are trying to do.  You require to run an agent (when you submit the signed documents), to just open the employee document and change the boolean so it presents accordingly within the view.  A scheduled agent is certainly not the answer.

You should also take a look at http://www.codestore.net/ too and see if there is anything similar on what you are trying to do already in Jake's sandbox.  Specially in those nsf's  that use Json and agents to interact with views in the DOM of the web app.

Please tale a look at http://www.codestore.net/apps/contacts.nsf/  it is downloadable and probably you will need to add a couple of ajax functions in the employee (customer in the example) when signing those documents.  That way, you can either run the agents conditionally, (if the employee has the flag for submitting those documents signed or not then run or not run the boolean setter for the employee doc) or running the agent by using ajax.